# Is there a home for opinion-based questions?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I can’t remember which question got me thinking, but after seeing several questions that were put on hold for being too opinion-based, I wondered where these questions can even be asked. Is there an active Stack Exchange or forum where opinion-based questions can be asked and answered?

Comment: HDE is correct.  There is no formal site for opinion based stuff, nor should there be, at least not on SE, that's just not what the network/system is designed for.  That said there are tons of forums out there on the web, and if you want to keep it here you can visit us in [chat], we talk about stuff like that all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not the first person to want this, nor will you be the last. Unfortunately, Stack Exchange doesn't have a place to ask these primarily opinion-based questions. [Many questions have some component of opinion and subjectivity to them](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/), of course, and that can work within the Stack Exchange model; Worldbuilding deals with much more subjectivity than the average site. But questions that are *primarily* opinion-based [usually don't work well in that format](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75940/274942).

Presumably, there's a non-Stack Exchange site out there that has more of a traditional forum style, which should accommodate this sort of question, but we don't have a place like that within the network. I'd advise searching for a place like that.